# Maven Dependencies taking too long to download

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

my spring boot project creation takes more than 3 hours just to download dependencies, for example Web, Devtools and JPA.

I am using intellij and using 
http://start.spring.io/

what could be the cause of failing to download such small sized dependencies

Comment: Maybe include a result from http://www.speedtest.net/ to show whether or not it's network related. Would also help to include some download logs

Comment: Maybe network Problems or unreachable repositories, try mvn -X ... to see debug informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have realised the problem was that i had allocated a smaller memory to Intellij
go to On the Help menu, click Edit Custom VM Options. and edit the Xmx 8224 means 8Gb allocated to intellij

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. 
It was because my maven repo was on a network drive while the application I was building was on a local drive.
When I moved the repo to the local drive it fixed the issue.

Comment: You mean the local cache? meaning $HOME/.m2/repository on a network drive? Yes this will explain a lot...